# Passing selection query referencing two joined records in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Suppose I have table called CustomerTransaction, I can pass a selection criteria to a routine like

```
void GetData1(Expression<Func<CustomerTransaction, bool>> selection)
{
    CustomerTransaction.Where(selection).Take(2).Dump();
}
```

using code like

```
Expression<Func<CustomerTransaction, bool>> query = r => (r.CustomerID == 1);
GetData1(query);
```

However, I would like to be able to join two records from this table and pass in a selection criteria referring to both tables.

For example, the following will compile (in LinqPad),

```
void GetData2(Expression<Func<Tuple<CustomerTransaction,CustomerTransaction>, bool>> selection)
{
   var baseQuery = (from ct1 in CustomerTransaction 
        join ct2 in CustomerTransaction on ct1.MasterTransactionID equals ct2.RelatedTransactionID 
        select new Tuple<CustomerTransaction, CustomerTransaction> ( ct1, ct2)) ;

    var query = baseQuery.Where(selection).Dump();
}

Expression<Func<Tuple<CustomerTransaction,CustomerTransaction>, bool>> query2 =
       r => r.Item1.CustomerID != r.Item2.CustomerID;

GetData2(query2);
```

However, it will not run because SQL does not handle the Tuple.

If I attempt to write this in some manner that SQL will understand, then I can't pass the selection criteria because I don't know the type of selection

eg

```
void GetData3( ???  selection)
{
    var baseQuery = (from ct1 in CustomerTransaction
     join ct2 in CustomerTransaction on ct1.MasterTransactionID equals ct2.RelatedTransactionID
     select new { Customer1 = ct1.CustomerID, Customer2 = ct2.CustomerID }  );

    baseQuery.Where(selection).Dump();
}
```

Obviously the real query is more complicated and they are multiple selection criteria, and I am trying to avoid duplicating the query for every possible section criteria.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an explicit class that represents your `join` result, and create your `Where` expression on that class:

```
public class CT2 {
    public CustomerTransaction ct1;
    public CustomerTransaction ct2;
}
```

Then you can use the class in your query and `Where` expression:

```
void GetData2(Expression<Func<CT2, bool>> selection) {
    var baseQuery = from ct1 in db.CustomerTransaction
                    join ct2 in db.CustomerTransaction on ct1.MasterTransactionID equals ct2.RelatedTransactionID
                    select new CT2 { ct1 = ct1, ct2 = ct2 };

    var query = baseQuery.Where(selection).Dump();
}

Expression<Func<CT2, bool>> query2 =
       r => r.ct1.CustomerID != r.ct2.CustomerID;

GetData2(query2);
```